# Using the result of a derivative, find the integral?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I'm just a little bit unsure of this question:

"Show that: $d/dx (\sin x)^3=3\cos x(\sin x)^2$ and hence use this result to find the integral (limits of $pi/2$ and $0$) of $(\sin x)^2\cos x.$"

Is it simply putting one third in front of the integral and multiplying $\cos x(\sin x)^2$ by 3 as well?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is a phrase for this: the "Net Change Theorem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the continuity of $f$ to conclude that $F(x) = \int_{c}^{x} f(t)\; dt$ holds the following properties that: i) $F'(x) = f(x)$ and ii) $F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)\; dt $.

So, $\int_{0}^{\pi /2} 1/3\cdot f(t)\; dt = 1/3 \cdot \int_{0}^{\pi /2} f(t)\; dt = 1/3\cdot ([\text{sin}(\pi/2)]^3 - [\text{sin}(0)]^3) = 1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly right. 
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\,\cos x=\left.\frac13\,\sin^3x\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac13.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $(\sin^3(x))' = 3\cos(x)(\sin^2(x))$. If follows that $\int_0^{1/2\pi} \cos(x)(\sin^2(x)) dx= \frac{1}{3}\int_0^{1/2\pi} 3\cos(x)(\sin^2(x)) dx = \frac{1}{3}(\sin^3(1/2\pi)-\sin^3(0))=\frac{1}{3}$.